# How to restart Phusion Passenger + Apache in Production mode on Ubuntu server for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

I am having Apache + phusion passenger, I have put

```
RailsEnv production
```

in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file and have restarted apache but when I am running

```
rails c
> Rails.env.production?
```

it gives fales where as for

```
> Rails.env.development?
```

it gives true. Is there any other way to restart passenger as I do think putting "RailsEnv production" in default is the right way ? btw I am using

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

How to start my ruby on rails app in Production mode with passenger + apache ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app is probably in production mode already.

By default, `rails c` loads the app in dvelopment mode.

If you want your console to be launched in production mode, do the following :

`RAILS_ENV=production rails c`

The console and the web app are two different rails proccess and run independently.

You should check your production.log file to be sure that your app runs in production.

Comment: you are right, the development.rb only has 4 entries but the production.rb is full so the server is certainly running in production mode.

Comment: you can also do this by typing 'rails console [environment]' e.g. rails console production

Answer (score 27):

just create a restart.txt in tmp dir of your app

e.g.

```
  touch %RAILS_ROOT%/tmp/restart.txt
```

look here 
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html section 3.3

Comment: How can I be sure this has its effect (I'm reorganizing my phusion/capistrano set-up)? Or, what is this "restart" needed for anyway?

Comment: Ah! I can tell it restarts by watching the Apache error log file (/var/log/apache2/error.log in my case) for something like: [ 2014-01-08 20:37:38.9069 32489/7ff921f67700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:301 ]: Preloader for /app01/akiary_registration/app started on PID 13325, listening on unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.32480/generation-0/backends/preloader.13325

Answer (score 3):

Just for starting app with particular port use below command:

**passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -d -e production**

Answer (score 3):

I followed the commands listed in PhusionPassenger docs [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/apache/restart_app.html) and they worked straight-away.

```
deployer@staging:~$ passenger-config restart-app
Please select the application to restart.
Tip: re-run this command with --help to learn how to automate it.
If the menu doesn't display correctly, press '!'

 ‣   /home/deployer/myapp/current (staging)
     /home/deployer/myapp_2/current (staging)
     Cancel

Restarting /home/deployer/myapp/current (staging)

deployer@staging:~$ passenger-config restart-app
Please select the application to restart.
Tip: re-run this command with --help to learn how to automate it.
If the menu doesn't display correctly, press '!'

     /home/deployer/myapp/current (staging)
 ‣   /home/deployer/myapp_2/current (staging)
     Cancel

Restarting /home/deployer/myapp_2/current (staging)
```