# upgrade redmine 2.3.3 to 2.5.1 does not work

Tags: svn, redmine

I have a turnkeylinux (v13.0) redmine appliance (redmine v2.2.3). 
I tried to upgrade v2.2.3 to v2.5.1 and followed the upgrade instructions.

I did not get any errors, but my version is still at v2.2.3!
what am I doing wrong?

RAILS_ENV=production script/about:

```
root@tkredmine www/redmine# RAILS_ENV=production  script/about
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.

Environment:
  Redmine version                          2.2.3.stable
  Ruby version                             1.9.3 (x86_64-linux)
  Rails version                            3.2.12
  Environment                              production
  Database adapter                         Mysql2
Redmine plugins:
  no plugin installed
```

The steps I did to upgrade redmine (as in the docs)

```
root@tkredmine /# cd /var/www/redmine
root@tkredmine www/redmine# svn
Type 'svn help' for usage.
root@tkredmine www/redmine# svn update
Skipped '.'
root@tkredmine www/redmine# bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.3.1)
Using i18n (0.6.9)
Using multi_json (1.9.3)
Using activesupport (3.2.12)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Using activemodel (3.2.12)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.5)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using sprockets (2.2.2)
Using actionpack (3.2.12)
Using mime-types (1.25.1)
Using polyglot (0.3.4)
Using treetop (1.4.15)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.12)
Using arel (3.0.3)
Using tzinfo (0.3.39)
Using activerecord (3.2.12)
Using activeresource (3.2.12)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using coderay (1.0.9)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.4)
Using json (1.8.1)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using thor (0.19.1)
Using railties (3.2.12)
Using jquery-rails (2.0.3)
Using metaclass (0.0.4)
Using mocha (0.12.3)
Using mysql2 (0.3.15)
Using net-ldap (0.3.1)
Using pg (0.17.1)
Using ruby-openid (2.1.8)
Using rack-openid (1.4.2)
Using rails (3.2.12)
Using shoulda (2.11.3)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.9)
Using test-unit (2.5.5)
Using yard (0.8.7.4)
Your bundle is updated!
Gems in the groups rmagick and install were not installed.
root@tkredmine www/redmine# rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
root@tkredmine www/redmine# rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
root@tkredmine www/redmine# rake tmp:cache:clear
root@tkredmine www/redmine# rake tmp:sessions:clear
```

I tried to restart passenger as told in the docs, but I do not know how.
How do you do that?
I did restart apache2, and even rebooted, but that did not work either

Any suggestions please?

update: I followed the advise (thanks @nanego!) below, and did an svn upgrade, but now I get this error in apache logs:I get now this apache error log

```
`05-05 15:21:39.3335 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr] 
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3336 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr] ArgumentError (A secret is required to generate an integrity hash for cookie session data. Use config.secret_token = "some secret phrase of at least 30 characters"in config/initializers/secret_token.rb):
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3336 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:319:in `ensure_secret_secure'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3336 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:284:in `initialize'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3336 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:231:in `new'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3336 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:231:in `signed'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3336 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:50:in `block in unpacked_cookie_data'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3337 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:57:in `stale_session_check!'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3337 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:48:in `unpacked_cookie_data'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3337 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:107:in `extract_session_id'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3337 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:53:in `block in extract_session_id'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3337 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:57:in `stale_session_check!'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3338 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:53:in `extract_session_id'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3338 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:43:in `load_session_id!'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3338 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:32:in `[]'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3338 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:267:in `current_session_id'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3338 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:273:in `session_exists?'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3339 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:107:in `exists?'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3339 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:127:in `load_for_read!'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3339 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:64:in `has_key?'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3339 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:258:in `ensure in call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3340 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:259:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3340 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3340 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3340 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3340 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3341 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3341 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3341 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2692797002708509105__call__4121954948629708039__callbacks'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3341 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3341 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3342 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3342 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3342 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3342 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3342 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3343 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3343 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3343 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3343 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3343 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3344 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3344 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3344 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3344 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3344 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3345 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3345 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3345 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3345 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3345 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3346 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3346 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   railties 
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3346 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr] (3.2.17) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3346 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3347 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   passenger (4.0.20) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3347 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   passenger (4.0.20) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:140:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3347 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   passenger (4.0.20) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:108:in `main_loop'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3347 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr]   passenger (4.0.20) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:441:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3347 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr] 
[ 2014-05-05 15:21:39.3348 175/7f60167f8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2905 stderr] `
```

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: what does it mean "I tried to restart passenger as told in the docs, but I do not know how"? What is instruction you following by

Comment: thanks for your reply gotva ;) the docs said to restart passenger. But they did not provide instructions how to do that. so what I did was restart apache2, and even rebooted, but that did not work either

Comment: (gotva, here is the link to the docs mentioned: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade, "see option 2")

Comment: try `touch %RAILS_ROOT%/tmp/restart.txt` (taken from this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368492/how-to-restart-phusion-passenger-apache-in-production-mode-on-ubuntu-server-fo))

Comment: I saw that before, but it did not help, sadly enough

Comment: does rails console work? run `bundle exec rails c`. Maybe some problems in your environment

Comment: I will try that later, but redmine (the old version) still runs, so I excpect that ruby works fine?

Comment: one more idea: as I understand you have Redmine 2.3.3 and you are trying to update it to 2.5.1. You update code and run `bundle update`. Bundle shows that you use `Using rails (3.2.12)` Why it is 3.2.12?! Redmine 2.5 stable uses rails [3.2.17](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/983ec24a97d4f7243d347da7b7fdfcf961153130/Gemfile#L3). It looks like you did not update code locally. If it is true I can suggest you to use git to update redmine code

Comment: "root@tkredmine ~# bundle exec rails c " gives
Could not locate Gemfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know what is your current SVN branch ?

You can use this command to know it:

```
svn info | grep URL
```

It seems the "svn update" command did not update your Redmine version.

You should try to change the branch you currently use and switch to the 2.5:

```
svn switch http://svn.redmine.org/redmine/branches/2.5-stable
```

Comment: Thanks nanego. Now I get this:
`Repository UUID: e93f8b46-1217-0410-a6f0-8f06a7374b81
Revision: 13129
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal

root@tkredmine www/redmine# svn switch http://svn.redmine.org/redmine/branches/2.5-stable
svn: Failed to add directory 'test': an unversioned directory of the same name already exists`

Comment: When you execute the "svn info" command, you see revision is 13129, which is currently the last commit on the trunk branch.

Comment: Do you get any error message when you run the "svn update" command?

Comment: Hi nanego, thanks to your hints I was able to upgrade via svn, I followed all steps on [http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade] (including moving the old config files) and they completed without error. But now I can not login to redmine.

Comment: the webpage gives this error: "Internal error

An error occurred on the page you were trying to access.
If you continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine administrator for assistance.

If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error." the redmine and apache logs don't give me a clue either

Comment: I included the apache log (see my question top of the page)

Comment: Apache logs say you have to specify the secret token. You can generate it with this command: rake generate_secret_token

Comment: Is there an installer or any stack like Helicon Zoo for 2.5.1 version in Windows ( Server 2k8r2 ent. x64 )?

Answer (score 1):

with upgrade, you might have to declare ownership again for the www folder.

I had no luck doing the SVN option. Here is what I did

I had alot of issues trying to follow just one walkthrough so I pieced together alot of them and found things that worked. I am in no way an expert on this nor am I even a novice.... I just have vshpere where I snapshot and then trial and error. Finally got it to work and I believe below is the only commands I used.

This is all done with a baseline turnkey redmine with 2.2.3. I had some plugins i wanted to try which required an upgrade... so here it is...

If you made any changes to the locales/en.yml then you will have to do it again. I wouldn't recommend copying that file over as the update might have some other language associations that werent with the older version.

**SNAPSHOT VM FIRST!!!****

`cd /var/www/
mv redmine redmine-old
wget http://www.redmine.org/releases/redmine-2.5.2.zip
unzip redmine-2.5.2.zip -d /var/www/
mv redmine-2.5.2 redmine
cp redmine-old/config/database.yml redmine/config/database.yml
cp redmine-old/config/configuration.yml redmine/config/configuration.yml
cp -r redmine-old/files redmine/
cp -r redmine-old/plugins redmine/
bundle install --without development test rmagick
bundle exec rake generate_secret_token
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
cd redmine
chown -R root:www-data /var/www/redmine
chown -R www-data:www-data files/ log/ tmp/ public/plugin_assets
reboot`

log into your webserver as admin=>administration=>information
and you should see that it was upgraded. Ensure that there is no error with the plugin write access. You may have to go in and change ownership of some stuff. This is where it got funky with mine and I forgot what I did so I think the above commands is what I did but not sure.